# Millions of records published to Message queue not displaying on RabbitMq Management dashboard screen

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have requirement of processing 2 Million rows of excel. I am publishing all the rows to RabbitMQ queue, I did not encounter any exceptions but unable to see them on Management console/dashboard for the queue. When I am publishing 50K records I am able to see on Management console. This issue is only when I am publishing 2 million objects to queue.

In addition to the above information , I am parsing each row of excel and making a pojo object out of it and adding all pojo's to list and publishing to message queue.

Is there any maximum count limit for any queue that I can change? or any memory space I need to increase to hold these many number (2 Million) of pojo's?

Can anyone suggest me the best way I can do to hold all the 2 million published objects in a queue by showing them on management console.

Comment: Try to ask the same question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users

Comment: Are you certain these messages are being routed to the queue(s) you expect? If RabbitMQ can't route a message, it is dropped!

Comment: Thanks Artem Bilian & Luke Bakken . The messages were not routed to the queue before due to some code issue. I fixed the issue and now able to get all 1 Million messages published to queue.